# using ruby for admin-script: bunder / gem / rvm confusion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, sudo

I have a git-repo which i clone onto my servers to do some administrative stuff. Most of the scripts are ruby, i need some gems. Until now i just installed the gems using sudo, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

I tried rvm and bundler, but i'm still not sure how to do it properly.

Usually i clone the repository into /root and symlink the scripts into /usr/local/bin. I think what i want is the gems to be installed into the repository itself, so that other people can use my scripts without fu*king up their rubygems installation.

Any ideas on how to proceed? I also don't know how to specify the gems in a way that the script in /usr/local/bin still find them.

Comment: Running the scripts from `/root` is probably a way bigger security concern than installing gems with `sudo`.

Comment: Why excactly? I can also put the git repo into /usr/local, but my question still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with RVM you can select separate gemset for gems and create a wrapper that will make binaries available always in PATH.

here is example with `haml`:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@tools --install --create
gem install haml
rvm wrapper 1.9.3@tools --no-prefix haml
```